# changing name of project in composer.json in fork/branch impossible?

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

i currently ran into a problem with renaming a project in composer.json.

the previos status was like the following:

```
{
    "name": "old/name",
    "license": "Business",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "description",
    "autoload": {},
    "minimum-stability":"dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.5",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.6",
      "mockery/mockery": "0.9.4",
      "leaphub/phpcs-symfony2-standard": "~2.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
    },
    "extra": {
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev",
        }
    }
}
```

now i need to change this to

```
{
    "name": "new/name",
    "license": "Business",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "description",
....
}
```

therefore i created a new branch, changed the information, created a branch-alias to reference it in the target-project.

```
...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:matthias-chlechowitz/forked-repo.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "new/name":"dev-matthias/rewrite-branchname"
        }
...
```

but when running composer update to fetch the updated version, the old version with the previous project name is fetched and the following error message appears:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package new/name could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

so it's not possible to rename projects within one repo or even forks? or am i missing a major part?

best regards,
matthias

Answer (score 3):

thank you for your answer, but referencing a new branch was not the problem (which was working perfectly fine). The problem was really changing the name of the project (name-property in the composer.json).

According to Christophe Coevoet [1], composer always fetches the name from the master branch, so my changes in forked or derived branches doesn't affect the outcome.

Best regards,
Matthias

[1] https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4677